# How to set the default font in AEM (Adobe Experience Manager)

Tags: fonts, configuration, aem, default

As shown below, I have set the standard font for my AEM website. However, the font shown is never applied no matter where I put font-family: FSAlbertPro or font-family: "FS Albert Pro" or font-family: FS Albert Pro. Where should I set the default font so that it can get applied? And how should I apply it since the customary ways are not working?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use `@font-face` rule to specify your custom font in the CSS.

For e.g.,

```css
    @font-face{
         font-family:'FS Albert Pro';
         font-style:normal;
         font-weight:normal;
         src:url('../fonts/FSAlbertPro/FSAlbertWeb-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/FSAlbertPro/FSAlbertWeb-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')
    }
```

Please replace the right file names for woff and ttf based on your file names in the fonts folder. [More info on font-face can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

If the font-face has been registered and you still don't see your fonts, verify if the font is loading currently in your browser using the Developer console. If you find a 404 for the font URL, verify the URL again and use the right one.